# jQuery UI Autocomplete: how do you start an asynchronous process and quit it before it finishes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete to build a search interface.

I have defined a custom function which returns search results and updates them automatically as keys are pressed however, sometimes this custom function doesn't complete before the next key is pressed (i.e. its still processing "Wash" when I have already written "Washi" (on the way to writing "Washington").

I would like every call to the autocomplete "source" event to cancel the previous function(Wash) and start the new function(Washi). With the next call cancelling function(Washi) and starting function (Washin) and so on.

How is this kind of thing done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var lastXhr;
$( "#myAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        if (lastXhr) lastXhr.abort();
        lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
            if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                response( data );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the `lastXhr` var stores the most current xhr request.  If there is one set and the source function is called then it aborts the lastXhr request and makes a new one.  When the ajax request returns if make sure that it matches the lastXhr, if not then it doesn't call the `response()` function.

Comment: Is there a way to wrap an arbitrary function/object so that it has an abort() method and runs in a way thats non-blocking? or will this trick only work with the $.getJSON wrapper?

Comment: @tjb abort is special to ajax requests.

Comment: Peterson, I think your answer is the right one and I accept it. But, would this work: I write the URL as something I know will always succeed, then I write a function that has nothing to do with the returned data but does something else useful. In that case would I be able to abort (even if the function was blocking), and in that way gain the above functionality with an arbitrary function?

Comment: Thank you tjb for asking this question (I was wondering the same thing!), and thank you @PetersenDidIt for this line, which I'd never seen before: if (lastXhr) lastXhr.abort();